# Installing Coldfusion 8 32 bit on a 64 bit machine - any problems?

Tags: windows, coldfusion, installation, 64-bit, 32-bit

We are planning to upgrade our test server and to do so we were planning on buying a 64 bit machine from Dell running Windows 2008 x64 Web edition.

However, for now we would like to continue to use 32 bit Coldfusion 8.

Is there anything to stop us doing this, or do we have to move to 64 bit Coldfusion 8?

Has anyone had any problems running 32 bit CF on 64 bit Windows recently? I see some people have had issues [before](http://www.jmpj.net/jason/index.cfm/2008/9/13/Installing-ColdFusion-801-Standard-on-64bit-Ubuntu-Hardy-from-woe-to-go) (not on Windows however) but I am assured by others that it will work just fine.

Many thanks in advance. 
Ciaran

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience this works fine.  However, you have to change the setup on IIS to allow 32-bit extensions, which (IIRC) disables 64-bit extensions.  Which means, basically, that if all you are doing on that machine is running IIS and CF, you might not see any gain.  However, if you are running other apps in 64-bit mode, need access to the memory, etc. then go for it.

Comment: Thanks Ben. And for others (and myself!), here are some instructions to switch IIS from 64 bit to 32 bit: http://www.ipconfig.co.nz/blog/post.cfm/switch-iis-from-64-bit-to-32-bit-mode

Comment: On your production server that is running Coldfusion 32 bit, can you simply run the 64 bit installer or do you have to uninstall 32 bit first and then reinstall 64 bit?

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason you want to stick with the 32 bit version?

For 32 Bit CF on Windows 2008 x64 instructions check this blog posting which has a section on 32 bit CF...

[ColdFusion 8 on Windows Server 2008](http://www.jasonholden.com/blog/index.cfm/2008/5/6/Coldfusion-8-on-Windows-Server-2008)

Comment: We just want to keep our test servers in step with our live servers (all 32 bit) for now. We'll upgrade to 64 bit CF on the test machine prior to getting our first 64 bit live production machines.

Comment: Standard 8 only comes in 32-bit only.  I don't know if this has changed in 9.